# Error when trying to start Gnome Screensaver

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, screensaver

When trying to start the screensaver

```
sudo gnome-screensaver-command -d
```

the following error occurs:

```
** Message: Failed to get session bus: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=5a30528c0bbe46b68b55c9f7b2514fea --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

When i use the command as my normal user i do not get any output.

When trying to lock the screen immediately with

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

nothing happens.

I am [following this link to solve the problem.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#D-Bus)
But i am not sure if this is the correct way. I am not familiar with the usage of *systemd*. And do i need to start the screensaver as a user srevice from *systemd* ? It seems a bit over complex. Am i missing someting?

Comment: Why are you trying to start it with `sudo`??

Comment: For generating something. When i do gnome-screensaver with either the -d or -l parameter as my user i get no output at all.

Comment: I'd say "no output at all" is _normal_ for this tool?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a while, but I think it deserves an answer. I had a problem exactly as described.

I found a solution in a [similar question of another forum](https://askubuntu.com/a/248349).
In my case, the gnome lock screen feature was disabled. To enable it again, I ran the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
```

Now you should be able to lock your screen again through keyboard shortcuts or by executing the following command:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```